Finding replacement for inductor that broke off my RTX 3090
I have the measurements as roughly 6.5mm x 6.7mm x 3.7mm (height)
I figure that a replacement can be purchased and attached, however I'm unsure which specific part to order. Can anyone assist with this?




It's a 4.7 uH inductor as that reads on top of it. All other parameters of it are unknown and thus nobody can tell which part to order and from where. And asking what to buy or from where is off-topic, so are repair questions.

^^^ Agreed with this comment. Even if you found a replacement, there's no guarantee that it would have the same DCR, which could affect efficiency for that power rail for the GPU. The power rail is built with those surrounding conditions.

You might be able to very carefully scratch away the shield and and reconnect the leads of the original inductor. You will likely need a microscope to do a good job at this.

solder the old one back on with generous amounts of solder; unlike plastic cases, the ceramic body can take a lot of heat and so you should be able to work it enough to re-connect the busted tabs.

Depending on the control method used by the dc-dc converter this inductor is a part of, you may be able to simply replace it with the highest-Isat, lowest-DCR 4.7 μH inductor you can find in the correct package. However, it's not uncommon to use the inductor's DCR itself as a "current shunt" to sense the current through the inductor, and if the converter does that, using an inductor with a very different DCR will cause issues. However, if the converter uses a different method to sense the current (it's almost certainly using current-mode control), the DCR won't matter much if it's kept low.
